# Алгоритм подсчета суммы ряда

Tags: c++, алгоритм

S = 1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + … + N^N

Cмоделировать арифметический цикл с помощью оператора цикла for. Формулу возведения в степень не использовать.

Comment: Мне кажется, если бы этот вопрос закрыли, было бы лучше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, попробуй:

```
int N=20,S=0, P=1;
for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
P=1;
for(int j=1;j<i;j++){
P = P*i;
}
S = S+P;
}
```

Comment: @mctrane чем больше мы отвечам на подобного рода вопросы из разряда "сделайте", тем ХешКод становится все менее профессиональным ресурсом.

Comment: Но ведь задача то простая

Comment: проверка: N=2 S=7, N=3 S=12, N=4 S=76 неверно.
я понимаю что при введении значения N должно получатся: N=2 S=4, N=3 S=27, N=4 S=256.

Comment: @mctrane ну вот смотрите - вы ответили на вопрос @Devil. Он, думая "ух ты, нашел сайт, где быстренько и нахаляву задачки решают!", приводит сюда толпу своих однокурсников\одноклассников\etc, с не менее банальными вопросами и, почти наверняка, не умеющих эти самые вопросы даже задавать. А так ли оно надо?

Comment: Нет, если по вашей формуле, то они должны складываться ещё. Проверил, при N=2, S=5, как и надо

Comment: VioLet, хорошо, больше не буду, убедили)

Comment: какие все злые.@mctrane прогу изменил, работает не корректно.

Comment: @Devil7, мы не злые. Просто, судя по всему, вы даже не подумали над решением задачки, а сразу написали сюда. Это не есть хорошо.

Comment: Пробуй сейчас, должно быть всё норм. N=2 - S=5
VioLet, их проблемы, не понимаю зачем учится на программиста, если не хочешь этому учится)

Answer (score 0):

Не вздумайте попробовать вышенаписанное!

```
const int N = 20;
long int S = 1;
for(int i = 2; i <= N; i++)
{
    long int P = 1;
    for(int j = 1; i <= j; j++)
    {
        P *= i;
    }
    S += P;
}
```

Comment: От моего кода совсем не отличается, разве что типы переменных поменялись

Comment: Теперь-то почти(!) не отличается, а раньше-то какую хрень писали! 
P = P *j *j(??). Да и теперь код написан с ошибками, так что работать не будет.
"Ты плохо-то не делай, ты хорошо делай. Плохо-то - само получится" Цитата.

Comment: Я просто додумывал... И каждую минуту редактировал код. Какие там ошибки?

Comment: Запустите, узнаете.